# Getting this error in the quality gate of the sonarqube [ 0.0,% Coverage on New Codeis less than 80.0% ]

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

[Sonarqube Project Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1tCI.png)

We have setup sonarqube through CI on jenkins where through groovy script i have created the groovy script to create a sonarqube for the particular project where i get this error

Till now i have trouble shoot this steps :
1.) In the Project Information changed Define a specific setting for this project where --> Number of days where i have Specify a number of days to 2 to cover only last two days code
2.) Try to create the new sonarqube project for the same project and rescan but still getting the same error.

Can any one have idea about it why it's happening and how to resolve it. and get passed the sonarqube quality gate status.